# I had created two packages(packageA & packageB). When i tried to import packageB func called message() to packageA i am getting an error. why?

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, package

```
/*This is  greeting file code from packageA*/

package packageA;

import packageB.message;

public class greeting {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("this is greeting from packagesSubA");
message();

}

}
```

---

```
/*This is message file  code from packageB*/

package packageB;


public class message {
public static void main(String[] args) {


}

public static void message(){
System.out.println("This is a message from packagesSubB " );  
}
}
```

I tried to run the greeting file code from packageA
expecting output like :-

```
this is greeting from packagesSubA
This is a message from packagesSubB
```

But I'm getting error like:-

```
    greeting.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    message.message("roshnin");
    ^
    symbol:   variable message
    location: class greeting
    2 errors
    error: compilation failed
```

Comment: Should be `message.message();` Class names [begin upper case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: maybe it is easier to see the structure of the code if using appropriate indentation...

Comment: Please indent your code properly, capitalize your class names, and show the code that actually matches the error message. You have obviously compiled a file that contains `message.message("roshnin")` but only showed us a file that calls `message()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling a method like this

```
message.message("roshnin");
```

it will call a method with a signature like this

```
public static void message(String message) {
```

but there is no such method in your class. Either change the call

```
//from 
message.message("roshnin");

//to
message.message();
```

or change the method to

```
public static void message(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```